# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode

I don't know exactly what's the source of this error and how to fix it. I am getting it by running [this code](https://github.com/gjreda/craigslist-checker/blob/master/craigslist.py).

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "t1.py", line 86, in <module>
        write_results(results)
      File "t1.py", line 34, in write_results
        dw.writerows(results)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 154, in writerows
        return self.writer.writerows(rows)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any explanation is really appreciated!

I changed the code and now I get this error:

```
 File "t1.py", line 88, in <module>
    write_results(results)
  File "t1.py", line 35, in write_results
    dw.writerows(results)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 154, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(rows)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the change:

```
 with codecs.open('results.csv', 'wb', 'utf-8') as f:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='|')
        dw.writer.writerow(dw.fieldnames)
        dw.writerows(results)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is raised by this part of the code:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='|')
    dw.writer.writerow(dw.fieldnames)
    dw.writerows(results)
```

You're opening an ASCII file, and then you're trying to write non-ASCII data to it. I guess that whoever wrote that script happened to never encounter a non-ASCII character during testing, so he never ran into an error.

But if you look at the docs for the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), you'll see that the module can't correctly handle Unicode strings (which is what Beautiful Soup returns), that CSV files always have to be opened in binary mode, and that only UTF-8 or ASCII are safe to write.

So you need to encode all the strings to UTF-8 before writing them. I first thought that it should suffice to encode the strings on writing, but the Python 2 `csv` module chokes on the Unicode strings anyway. So I guess there's no other way but to encode each string explicitly:

In `parse_results()`, change the line

```
results.append({'url': url, 'create_date': create_date, 'title': title})
```

to

```
results.append({'url': url, 'create_date': create_date, 'title': title.encode("utf-8")})
```

That might already be sufficient since I don't expect URLs or dates to contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I changed the code but I yet the same error. Can you please check my updated post? Were you able to run this program without error yourself?

Comment: Hmm, that's the same error, but it occurs on a different line. If you had just switched the two blocks, the line numbers should remain identical - did you change anything else?

Comment: I came here through google search and this change fixed the error for me. Funnily, for me "&nbsp;" was  causing python to choke. Is this expected?

Comment: @user763410: The literal text `&nbsp;` should be OK, but the character encoded by that entity is outside the ASCII range, so it might in fact cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. works for me. Code snippet

```
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
data = [["a", "b", u'\xe9']]
with open("output.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(data)
```